# How to remove all the backslash in a text coming from firebase and displaying it to html

Tags: html

i want to remove all the backslash in the text below:

```
https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/sad-police-app.appspot.com\/o\/October 7 19:28:1?alt=media&token=d18ae430-c717-45b4-a82a-6dfefc0756dd
```

I'm getting that data above from my fire base database and i display it on web, but suddenly the picture link has a backslash. i want to remove all the \ or backslash in the link so that i can copy and paste the link and view the picture directly. help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Javascript

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

EDIT 1 :

To remove " and \ use below:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(/[\\"]/g, '');
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much. i have 1 more question. what if i want also to remove all the " and \ on the text below: `"https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/sad-police-app.appspot.com\/o\/October 7 19:28:1?alt=media&token=d18ae430-c717-45b4-a82a-6dfefc0756dd"` 
can you give me code that will remove 2 special character? thank you so much

Comment: mystring = mystring.replace(/[\\"]/g, '');

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
var result = url.replace('\','');
```

url is your firebase data.

(or) try this way.

```
var result = url.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much. i have 1 more question. what if i want also to remove all the " and \ on the text below: `"https:\/\/firebasestorage.googleapis.com\/v0\/b\/sad-police-app.appspot.com\/o\/October 7 19:28:1?alt=media&token=d18ae430-c717-45b4-a82a-6dfefc0756dd"` 
can you give me code that will remove 2 special character? thank you so much

Comment: var result = url.replace(/[~!@#$]/gi,''); You can add multiple symbols in the [ ] brackets.

Comment: how about if i got a text like this below:
`https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sad-police-app.appspot.com/o/Time?alt=media&token=6cb588bf-182b-48be-88bd-1d2b804ecebe`
how can i make it to a clickable link?

Comment: im just getting the link from my firebase data and displaying it to web. i want it to be clickable when the link go to web